# WebStorm: define variables in separate JS file?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have split all my functions into a separate `functions.js` file.  I am defining my variables in the `main.js` script file. WebStorm throws warnings that my variables are implicitly declared or that they are never used.

Is there a way to reference `script.js` from `functions.js`?

I tried adding `scripts.js` to the "libraries" screen at the project level but this did not help.

**Definitions in script.js**

[image: Definitions in script.js]

**Variable implicitly declared**

[image: Variable implicitly declared]

more:

> Checks JavaScript variables to be declared explicitly with var statement. The validation works in JavaScript, html or jsp files.

Comment: Regardless of how it's done in WebStorm, what you're describing is bad practice (global variables). Consider using the module pattern (or even a module library) to mitigate risks involved with globals.

Comment: I agree with the not a good practice, but just as an aside, I am a little surprised WebStorm isn't picking up the variables. IntelliJ (which is in effect WebStorm + Java) frequently surprises me with how well it divines what is going on across a pile of JS files.

Comment: please provide exact code samples. WebStorm (and Idea) indexes all .js files in project, so variables defined in one file should be known in other. Error screenshot would be also helpful